# php ldap_search not returning results

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm establishing a connection to our Active Directory listing of users/employees.  I've done this through .NET, but cant get it to work in my PHP app.

I consistantly get a count of 0.

I've tried using samaccountname and sAMaccountname as filters, this does not change the result.

I am successfully connecting, as changing the $ldap will no longer find the server.

I am using valid credentials, as changing $authUser or $authPath provide an authorized error message.

The ldap_bind (i presume) is working, because it does perform the search and outputs a count of 0.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
try{
    $ldap = "vmc-dc.CompanyName.vmc";
    $authUser = "vmc\\MyUsername";
    $authPass = "MyPassword";
    $baseDn = "dc=vmc-dc,dc=CompanyName,dc=com";
    $filter="(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=*))";

    $conn = ldap_connect($ldap, 389) ;

    if ($conn) {

        ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        // binding to ldap server
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($conn, $authUser, $authPass);

        // verify binding
        if ($ldapbind) {
            //$sr=ldap_read($conn, $baseDn, $filter);
            $sr=ldap_search($conn, $baseDn, $filter);  

            $number_returned = ldap_count_entries($conn,$sr);
            echo "Count: " . $number_returned . "<br/>";

            $entry = ldap_get_entries($conn, $sr);
            ldap_close($conn);
            echo "value = '" . $entry[0] . "'";

        } else {
            echo "LDAP conn ok...";
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
?>
```

Comment: Verify that you can retrieve the desired data using the ldapsearch command line tool: `ldapsearch -h hostname -p port -b baseDn -s sub -D dn -w password "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=*))" 1.1`.

Comment: If you want all your users, `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))` is going to be your best bet for a filter.

Comment: To Brian's point, the need for objectCategory=person is to exclude computer objects.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your filter is too broad, all user class objects (which includes computers, to Brian Desmond's point) and is returning more than 1000 found objects. In which case AD will error, and return nothing.  I would expect you would get a returned error, so this may not be likely.  But a more constrained filter, and/or a repetition with a standalone LDAP tool could help validate this idea.